# .innerHTML to generate a new input?

Tags: javascript, input, append

i'm trying to use .innerHTML and appendChild to generate a new input with a value that is equal to a 's value. However it doesn't seem to be working and I don't understand why..

Here is my JS code:

```
function generateClass() {
      var value = document.getElementById("Classes").value;
       var originalDiv = document.getElementById("selectDiv");
            var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='class' value='" + value + "' disabled />"
            originalDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
      }
```

The select is simply:

```
<select name="class" id="Classes">
```

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: *"...doesn't seem to be working..."* isn't a useful problem statement. What do you expect, what do you see instead, what errors do you see in the console, what do you see when you step through the code with the debugger built into your browser, ...? *(Sorry to pepper you with questions, but this is the sort of information you want to supply to get good answers.)*

Comment: sorry, I meant to say, I was most confused by the fact that the console doesn't give an error, it simply does nothing on click (however I know it does call the function as I replaced all the functions code with an alert and on click, this alert was popped up)

Comment: Possible to provide the rest of the html/JS? I assume you're using some kind of `.onchange` functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys,
I've fixed my problem, i'd been an idiot with some earlier JS code.
Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Not a problem. Your best bet is just to delete the question (you can do that, since it has no upvoted answers).